# Is it possible to find out (retrospectively) when a file was deleted from standard Windows 7 logs?

Tags: windows, security, logging, events, viewer

My mother-in-law has a problem at her workplace: when she came back after a day off, a folder with important files was gone from the desktop, the trash bin also emptied, with several weeks' worth of work lost. Due to internal reasons, she suspects that the colleague she shares the office with deleted the file during her day off, with malicious intent (she's after her job). The colleague has access to the computer and logged on to it for work.

Perhaps I should add that my mother-in-law has been working there for a long time (as a senior accountant), knows how to work with computers and probably wouldn't just delete (and empty the bin on) an important folder, in a momentary lapse of reason.

Is it possible to find out when the folder was deleted, when the trash bin was emptied, or something along those lines, that would corroborate our suspicions? To my knowledge, no local group policies were configured on the machine beforehand. I was thinking that might be possible through the log files / event viewer, but that's just a hunch (I'm on mac myself and, unfortunately, don't have access to the machine). All I know is that it's Windows 7, I can add what exact version once she finds out. I might be able to log on through RDP, but that's a big if.

Comment: What you describe is unlikely. If the file was contained within the user’s profile only an Administrator could access their profile. However, only the user itself, could empty the recycling bin. Has the Administrator been contacted? A companies accountants file going missing should be reported.

Comment: What security software is the computer running, there is a chance that there is some XDR/EDR software on the computer that journals activity such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not after the fact.  You would have to set up file auditing before the deletion.

So there is nothing you can do from a systems perspective.

There is likely nothing you can do from a Human Resources perspective but you would have to ask them.

Another reason to have separate and secure backups.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And backups, yeah, I guess you have to go through it once before you start appreciating a good backup architecture :)